# Xamarin: Could not install the application AMDeviceSecureInstallApplicationBundle returned: 0xe8008015

Tags: ios, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am trying to deploy my app on the device to test.

In Debug mode I can deploy it successfully and it is working perfectly.

But when I am trying to deploy in Release mode it is giving me this error.

```
error MT1006: Could not install the application
'/Users/development/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/AppName.iOS/longstring/bin/iPhone/Release/AppName.iOS.app'
on the device 'My iPhone': AMDeviceSecureInstallApplicationBundle returned: 0xe8008015.
```

Have anyone faced this issue? how I can deploy the App on my testing device in release mode?

I have already tried recreating the certificate and provisioning profile.

I am using visual studio 2019.

Comment: try deleting the debug version (or any existing versions) of the app from the device

Comment: @Jason I did this as well but got no success.

Comment: Had you tried to search this error? You can check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/625819/xamarin-ios-unable-to-deploy-to-physical-device.html) and [the other](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/amdevicesecureinstallapplicationbundle-returned-0x-2/1171749)

Comment: Yes, I did, I tried resolving the issue. but still receiving the same issue.

Comment: Had you tried to update the visual studio?

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT Yes, I did. I am using Visual Studio Enterprise 2019 `version 16.11.16`

Comment: You can try to update the visual studio to version 2022.

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT I was able to resolve this issue by downloading the `Worldwide Developer Relations - G3 (Expiring 02/20/2030 00:00:00 UTC)` certificate from `https://www.apple.com/certificateauthority/`. But now after getting deployed App is freezing on the splash screen.

Comment: Can you provide more details such as logs or post a new question? We can't ensure what causes the freezing according to the information above.

Comment: @TheHunterShergill Did you solve the problem?

Comment: @AhmedShamel Yes, I found the mistake I was doing with `Signing Identity` and `Provisioning Profile`. I was using a Distribution Certificate to deploy in release mode but should be using Ad-Hoc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I thought I should post the answer to this question.

I found the mistake I was doing with `Signing Identity and Provisioning Profile`. I was using a `Distribution Certificate` to deploy in release mode but should be using `Ad-Hoc`.

Answer (score 2):

Check Your Entitlement plist and Enable / Disable push notification.
Then try to debug

Answer (score 1):

What fixed it for me is to remove the section I had in my Entitlements.plist. Not sure if it matters but our project is .NET6(net6-ios), formerly Xamarin.

Before:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" 
"http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>keychain-access-groups</key>
        <array>
            <string>com.mycompany.blah</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

After:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" 
"http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had implemented push notifications in my app by watching online tutorial. In that tutorial, the guy checked the checkbox of Push Notifications in the Entitlements.plist in Visual Studio 2022. This file is also available in other versions of Visual Studio as well. But Design and UI might differ.

So i checked it as well along with other configurations.
Due to this, i wasn't able to create an Adhoc IPA. While i was trying to debug it, i was keep getting the solutions related to profile provisioning in the apple account. I tried creating the profile provisioning again but it didn't fix my problem. It took me couple of days to fix this but finally i did it by disabling the checkbox of Push Notifications in the Entitlements.plist.

With this, i was able to create an Adhoc IPA but it might cause some issues when you are going to submit your build on AppStore.

So to resolve this issue, if you are working with development(debugging), open Entitlements.plist file code and check that your aps-environment should be set to "development" and set aps-environment to "production" if you are trying to create Adhoc with release mode.

[Debug mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z4Di1.png)
[Release mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WMBz3.png)

Answer (score -1):

For me it was setting the deployment target in the info.plist